# Issue with SQL Select Command Using Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I've written this SQL command

```
select MA.muncipilitycode, RD.specialnumber, OSL.documenttype, OSL.workpermitserial, OSL.workpermityear, MA.applicationnumber
from vls$licenseapplication LA,
     gam$mainapplication MA,
     gam$regdoc RD,
     gam$regdoc_mainapplication RDMA,
     gam$occstruct_app OSMA,
     gam$occstructlic OSL
where
     RD.specialnumber is not null and
     MA.applicationnumber is not null and
     OSL.documenttype is not null and
     OSL.workpermitserial is not null and
     OSL.workpermityear is not null and
     RDMA.gam$regdocid = RD.id and
     OSMA.GAM$MAINAPPLICATIONID = RDMA.GAM$MAINAPPLICATIONID and
     OSL.id = OSMA.GAM$OCCSTRUCTLICID
```

and its basically returning the same record (i've checked the first 800).

I dont want to share the record cause it is sensitive data

I believe that its repeating for the same entry multiple times. How can I rewrite it so that it only creates one instance of the same record.

EDIT : I've tried group by but I got this error ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY

Comment: Have you tried using SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92.

Comment: You don't have nearly enough joins in your `WHERE` clause.  You are ending up with a cartesian join for your LA and MA tables.  I agree modern syntax would help this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some join conditions. The explicit `join` syntax makes it harder to miss:

```
select ma.muncipilitycode, rd.specialnumber, osl.documenttype, osl.workpermitserial, osl.workpermityear, ma.applicationnumber
from   vls$licenseapplication la
       join gam$mainapplication ma
            on  ma.??? = la.???  -- Here
       join gam$regdoc rd
            on  rd.??? = ???     -- and here
       join gam$regdoc_mainapplication rdma
            on  rdma.gam$regdocid = rd.id
       join gam$occstruct_app osma
            on  osma.gam$mainapplicationid = rdma.gam$mainapplicationid 
       join gam$occstructlic osl
            on  osl.id = osma.gam$occstructlicid 
where  rd.specialnumber is not null
and    ma.applicationnumber is not null
and    osl.documenttype is not null
and    osl.workpermitserial is not null
and    osl.workpermityear is not null
```

Comment: .
.
.
from   gam$regdoc rd
       join gam$regdoc_mainapplication rdma
            on  rdma.gam$regdocid = rd.id
       join gam$mainapplication ma
            on  ma.id = rdma.gam$Mainapplicationid
       join gam$occstruct_app osma
            on  osma.gam$mainapplicationid = rdma.gam$mainapplicationid 
       join gam$occstructlic osl
            on  osl.id = osma.gam$occstructlicid 
.
.
.

Edit: la is not needed for the script at all